# get range of dates and by the first

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have two dates:

@dateini
@dateend

and i want to filter by two dates.

```
ID | NAME | DATE INI   | DATE FIN
1  | A    | 1/03/2019  | 31/03/2019   
2  | B    | 1/03/2019  | 3/05/2019
```

If i put 1/03/2019 - 31/03/2019 or 9/03/2019 - 31/03/2019

```
ID | NAME | DATE INI   | DATE FIN
1  | A    | 1/03/2019  | 31/03/2019

((@dateini <= Date2 and Date1 <= @dateini) AND (@dateend>= Date1 and Date2 >= @dateend))
```

thats my query but I want to know how to show it when it only includes the **first date**  31/03/2019 - 15/05/2019

```
ID | NAME | DATE INI   | DATE FIN
1  | A    | 1/03/2019  | 31/03/2019
```

Thx

Comment: maybe you can retry by using `between` operator

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, but the logic to check for overlapping ranges is: `date_start1 <= date_end2 and date_end1 >= date_start1` (eventually without `=`)

Comment: Your question isnt clear, you put some ranges but you dont explain the logic behind that

Comment: If like dnoeth said you want overlap dates ranges check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap

Comment: What's wrong with BETWEEN? "By the first" - use MIN then TOP 1 perhaps